# Ansible 'uri' module: How to return content from API?

Tags: ansible

The API is supposed to return a 10 letter string and using `curl` command on the API URL returns the correct string. The Ansible `uri` module is returning a status message.

```yaml
- name: Get variable output from api 
    uri:
      url: "http://apiurl"
    register: my_variable

  - name: Print my_variable
    debug:
      msg: "Value of the variable is {{ my_variable }}"
```

The message is:

```json
"msg": "Value of the variable {'redirected': False, 'url': 'http://apiurl', 'status': 200, 'server': 'nginx/1.10.3', 'date': 'Thu, 27 Oct 2022 17:47:49 GMT', 'content_type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'content_length': '23', 'connection': 'close', 'cookies_string': '', 'cookies': {}, 'msg': 'OK (23 bytes)', 'elapsed': 0, 'changed': False, 'failed': False}"
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the result of the task which means you can then access all attributes of the task. if you want the response content then you need to set the `return_content` attribute as detailed in the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-return_content)

```
Whether or not to return the body of the response as a “content” key in the dictionary result no matter it succeeded or failed.

Independently of this option, if the reported Content-type is “application/json”, then the JSON is always loaded into a key called json in the dictionary results.

Choices:

no ← (default)

yes
```

The docs also provide examples on how to use this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#examples

```yaml
- name: Check that a page returns a status 200 and fail if the word AWESOME is not in the page contents
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: http://www.example.com
    return_content: yes
  register: this
```

you could then access `this.content` to get the body of the response. Alternativly you could just use the `get_url` module and access the body attribute